# How to echo data array

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, echo

I'm new for this, can anyone solve my problem?
this is my code :

```
<?php

$data = array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
$datastart = 3;
$string = join(',', $data);
echo $string;

?>
```

This echo will be result :

```
Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday
```

I want a result like this:

```
Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday
```

thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice) to extract the portions of your array in the order you want to output them, and then [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to put them back together:

```
$data = array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
$datastart = 3;
$string = implode(',', array_merge(array_slice($data, $datastart), array_slice($data, 0, $datastart)));
echo $string;
```

Or you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
$len = count($data);
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $string .= ($i > 0 ? ',' : '') . $data[($i + $datastart) % $len];
}
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/T1jnE)